# how do i know whether my html link is clicked or not from Servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

My Servlet response type is html and my response contains a hyperlink to another web site.So, now i want to capture the information about whether the user clicked the link or not? and also calculate the total clicks? i am using Tomcat 7 as a server.

Is this possible in setting response header (302 or 404)?...

Please Guide me to get out of this issue?

Comment: i'd recommend Google Analytics for this...

Comment: Let that link do a `get` request on your server and then issue a browser redirect

Comment: If the link in your response doesn't come back to a page on your site, then you can't determine whether or not its been clicked. You could, for example, return a link that sends the user to one of your servlets along with some data about where to re-direct them (like prajeesh said).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a 302: instead of providing the link to the other website, you provide a link to your own servlet, do your accounting and then send back a redirection (301/302) http status with the other web-site URL in the response `Location` header.

This maybe a bit simplistic though, since the user will leave your original page (is this what you want ?) and search engines may not like this if your web app is public.

Answer (score 1):

I think right now you are redirecting the request(link for another website) at client side.In this approach your server cannot get the information about the click.

What you can do create a servlet and call this servlet on click now this servlet is responsible to redirect the request to another website. Add an static integer counter and increment this when servlet call each time.

Answer (score 1):

Use the method setStatus():-

```
setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FOUND);
```

or

```
setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
```